# Wordpress how to customize post tags for a post

Tags: wordpress, post, meta

I have a post with multiple post tags associated with it. In the post-edit form, in a textarea named "post_tags" I am displaying them in a comma separated string. Now I need the following:

1. If user add a new keyword it will be added to wp_terms and associated with the post.
2. If user deletes any term from that list it will just dissociate it from the post's association and will not delete from the wp_terms table.

I have managed to do the first point but I am stuck with the second. Doe anyone have any great idea to overcome this situation?

Comment: Have you tried the `wp_update_post` function? Like that you should be able to set post tags in an array argument.